# Matlab: Average of several discrete signals

Tags: matlab

I have 100 discrete signals with 70 values which sampled from a hardware device during a time interval with 100 different configurations. 
In each discrete signal, X show time and Y show sampled value at that time. We have 70 (X,Y) pairs for each signals as I noticed.

I want to find average of these 100 signal. My problem is that X values for each signal is not same as the other ones, it means we may have value (X1=100,Y1=...) for first signal and (X2=101,Y2=...) for 2nd signal. and Signal1 may have no samples at time 101.

As an exampled here is a part of 1st signal:

```
X,      Y
410,    2.0148
440,    2.0148
470,    2.0148
500,    331.7024
521,    335.9808
542,    192.8694
```

and values 2nd one is like this:

```
X,      Y
450,    2.0148
480,    2.0148
501,    689.6107
522,    176.0644
550,    271.8175
```

As you notice 1st one value in time=440 is 2.0148 but 2nd one have no value in time 440 but have in 450.

I Want to know are there any commands to calculate average of these 100 discrete signals?

Comment: can you clarifiy your question a little bit better? it's pretty unclear still what you want. You want to interpolate data from the 2nd sample on?

Comment: I think you are looking for interpolation which is matlab `interp1` in matlab http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html

Comment: @GameOfThrows question updated

Comment: @16per9 question updated for calrification

Comment: Is each signal independent of the other signals?  For example, if we had one signal with time value 440, for another signal that doesn't have time value 440, do you wish to find some interpolation or average value at time 440 using only that other signal's information?  Also, how are these signals being stored?... **Please** don't tell me they're in individual arrays :(

Comment: @rayryeng Each signal is independent of others. I one to work with them like continuous signals. It means value in point 440 should be something like `avergae(intrporlation(sig1@440), intrporlation(sig2@440),....,intrporlation(sig100@440))`

Comment: @VSB That's fine.... now do you have 100 separate variables, or is this perhaps in one matrix or cell array? Having 100 variables is difficult to work with

Comment: @rayryeng it is in matrix, each row is different signal, columns show 't', value of cell show 'y' value for each (signal,time) pair

Comment: @VSB Just to clarify... you are mixing "matrix" and "cell" together.  Is this a 2D matrix or a 1D cell array?

Comment: @rayryeng give me some time, I don't know the difference yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109939/discussion-between-vsb-and-rayryeng).

Comment: @rayryeng Let us continue this discussion in chat.